# Regression Hypothesis Testing for multivariate models

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I am running some linear regression models in R using the `lm` function and calling the `summary()` function on my linear model gives a nice summary of the degrees of freedom, F-statistic, sum of squares, etc.

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + b + c + d, data = my_data)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-0.0313491 -0.0034180 -0.0000105  0.0030041  0.0306064 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     1.004e-04  3.396e-04   0.362    0.717    
a              -2.739e-02  0.893e-02  -1.447    0.149    
b               5.019      5.127e-01  19.249   <2e-16 ***
c               7.090      2.954e-01  31.171   <2e-16 ***
d               4.241      2.760e-01  22.978   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.006236 on 354 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.881, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8797
```

Now, this gives p-values  / significance tests based on the null hypothesis that: $$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 =\mu_3 =\mu_4 = 0$$

Therefore, since each p-value is statistically significant at $\alpha=0.05$, we can reject the null hypothesis and conclude there is a linear relationship between each variable and the response variable.

Now I am interested in determining if one variable is statistically different from another variable, i.e. that it my model can be simply explained by just $b$ or just $b$ and $c$, etc. (I guess this is the same as determining if a  two variables are co-linear but I am uncertain.)

What tools can I use clarify this and find the most significant model?

Comment: I think that you want to do an analysis of covariance. In R try,   aov(formula = y ~ a + b + c + d, data = my_data)

Comment: @BradS. I did this but I don't know how to interpret the results when I feed it 2 models for comparison...I searched around for a detailed explanation but I found nothing

Comment: Note that comparing models with Anova requires them to be nested within one another.

Comment: The p-values reported in this output do *not* correspond to the (single) hypothesis you quote.  They correspond to four distinct hypotheses: $\mu_1=0$, $\mu_2=0$, *etc*.  These four p-values do *not* tell you whether you can reject the null hypothesis of no linear relationship: that is the purpose of the F test (which you eliminated from the bottom of the output).

Comment: @whuber So the individual p-values from the t-tests are whether each individual variable is significant and the final F-statistic's p-value tests the null that all coefficients are zero?

Comment: Even with a large F value, individual relationships can be not exactly linear. There are tests for regression assumptions. See https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/checking-glm-model-assumptions-in-r/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at comparing models, not comparing covariates really. If you have the models in mind, that is, you want to compare model $a$ to model $b$, you can use AIC, which estimates the fit of a model while taking its complexity into account: `aic(model_a,model_b)` and choose the lower outcome AIC model.

Another method, is using the adjusted $R^2$ of all the models you want and compare them. Generally, the model with the smallest amount of covariates and the highest adjusted $R^2$ is your winner. If you want to check all covariate combinations instead of manually choosing specific models to compare, you can use an all subsets regression from `library(leaps)` in R. This will allow you to choose the number of best combinations to show, which you can also `plot()` for a visual aid. If this is what you need, see [this great tutorial from R-studio pubs](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2897_9220b21cfc0c43a396ff9abf122bb351.html).

It might be worth noting that choosing the *fittest* model should be done with care. I come from social sciences, and the way I see it, sometimes it is worth adding non-significant covariates to the model - it they have a meaning. As a simple example, if I check for predictors of salary, and gender is non-significant, than perhaps some other covariate made it non-significant. If so - that is of interest. If not, than perhaps there is no gender pay-gap - also interesting. My point is Choose a model with care, not just by looking at the numbers - they do not always convey the entirety of the picture.